# How to create a Crosstab Plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I would like to create a 'Crosstab' plot like the below using `matplotlib` or `seaborn`:

[image]

Using the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['A', 'C', 2], ['A', 'D', 8], ['B', 'C', 25], ['B', 'D', 30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['col', 'row', 'val'])

  col row  val
0   A   C    2
1   A   D    8
2   B   C   25
3   B   D   30
```

An option in `matplotlib` could be by adding `Rectangle`s to the origin via `plt.gca` and `add_patch`. The problem is that I did here all manually like this:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
plt.xlim(-10, 40)
plt.ylim(-40, 40)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10,16)

someX, someY = 0, 0
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX, someY), 30, 30, facecolor="purple"))
ax.text(15, 15, '30')
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX, someY), 25, -25, facecolor="blue"))
ax.text(12.5, -12.5, '25')
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX, someY), -2, -2, facecolor="red"))
ax.text(-1, -1, '2')
currentAxis.add_patch(Rectangle((someX, someY), -8, 8, facecolor="green"))
ax.text(-4, 4, '8')
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the plot doesn't look that nice. So I was wondering if it is possible to somehow automatically create 'Crosstab' plots using `matplotlib` or `seaborn`?

Comment: Why xlim(-10, 40)?

Comment: I mean, that's the reason why your squares are not squares.

Comment: Not perfectly square tho, because I missed another reason: the whole figure itself isn't square. Plus, You may want to avoid big empty area. So, what you have to do is choose both xlim/ylim and the size of the figure to that squares are squares.

Comment: For example going back to your previous xlim(-10,40) ylim(-40,40) [which was worse from a ratio point of view, but better from a filling point of view], you need a 5/8 aspect ratio for your figure.

Comment: So keep -10/40 -40/40 after all. But choose a figsize such as (5,8) or (10,16) or (2.5,4) etc.

Comment: Thanks, @chrslg, edited my question. Now looks better. But it is not the mean issue of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether `matplotlib` or `seaborn` have dedicated functions for this type of plot or not, but using `plt.bar` and `plt.bar_label` instead of `Rectangle` and `plt.Text` might help automatize things a little (label placement etc.).

See code below:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['A', 'C', 2], ['A', 'D', 8], ['B', 'C', 25], ['B', 'D', 30]]
pos={'A':-1,'B':0,'C':-1,'D':1} 
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
p=[ax.bar(pos[d[0]]*d[2],pos[d[1]]*d[2],width=d[2],align='edge') for d in data]
[ax.bar_label(p[i],labels=[data[i][2]], label_type='center',fontsize=18) for i in range(len(data))]
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]